# How to reload tableview from another view controller in swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

When I dismiss a modal view controller I want the tableview to update, I am using the form sheet presentation style on iPad so the `viewWillAppear` and the `viewDidAppear` methods will not work

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter to fire a method that update your tableview.

Comment: Can u show me how, im not very familiar with NSNotificationCenter thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can do this:

In your tableView Controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
}
 
@objc func loadList(notification: NSNotification){
    //load data here
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Then in the other ViewController :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

Comment: This isn't working for me for some reason. I added a breakpoint at the line `//load data here` but the table view doesn't show the new data added

Comment: Thanks, this perfect solution, I was looking for some thing like this.

Comment: Worked for Me, I even called the `postNotificationName` function from a separate class, not even a viewcontroller

Comment: @ZackShapiro try to set that         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
            
            }); rather than self.tableView.reloadData() , it worked for me

Comment: This answer should be marked, it works, it's clean and understandable.

Comment: Perfectly!! I'm searching a way to reload like 3 tableView's data in 3 VC from other VC. Now I could sync the data in which is not current active VC. Thanks, bro.

Answer (score 51):

Swift 3 version code:
In your first view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
    }

func loadList(){
        //load data here
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

In your second view controller:

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
```

Comment: where in the second VC?

Comment: Anywhere in your second view controller where you think it's time to update the tableView possibilities are: methods, viewDidLoad or with in any part of code.. Hope its helpful

Comment: great, lifesaver solution!

Answer (score 2):

Missing comma on this line, should instead be:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "loadList:", name:"load", object: nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

I find the segue approach more elegant.

Let's say that we have `ViewControllerA` and a `ViewControllerB`. We are at `ViewControllerB` and we want from `ViewControllerB` to jump straight back to `ViewControllerA` and update the table view in `ViewControllerA`.

In `ViewControllerA` add the following action in your ViewController class:

```
@IBAction func unwindToViewControllerA(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

**Yes, this code goes in the ViewController of the ViewController you want to go back to!**

Now, you need to create an exit segue from the `ViewControllerB`'s storyboard (`StoryboardB`). Go ahead and open `StoryboardB` and select the storyboard. Hold CTRL down and drag to exit as follows:

[image]

You will be given a list of segues to choose from including the one we just created:

[image]

You should now have a segue, click on it:

[image]

Go in the inspector and set a unique id:
[image]

In the `ViewControllerB` at the point where you want to dismiss and return back to `ViewControllerA`, do the following (with the id we set in the inspector previously):

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "yourIdHere", sender: self)
```

Now, whenever you use the segue to return back to `ViewControllerA`, the `ViewControllerA` will update the TableView straightaway.

Answer (score 1):

**An alternate solution:** override `UIViewController`'s `dismiss(animated:completion:)` method on the view controller that manages the table view (and presents the other one modally), so you can reload the table then:

```
override func dismiss(animated flag: Bool, completion: (() -> Void)? = nil) {
    super.dismiss(animated: flag, completion: completion)

    self.tableView.reloadData()    
}
```

**Note:** This should work even if you call dismiss(animated:completion:) on the modal view controller itself (a viable alternative), because ultimately the call gets relayed to the *presenting* view controller.

From the method's docs:

> The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. If you call this method on the **presented** view controller itself, UIKit asks the **presenting** view controller to handle the dismissal.

*(emphasis mine)*

Answer (score 0):

You can use NotificationCenter to update your tableview.

First add observer...

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(doThisWhenNotify(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)

func doThisWhenNotify(notification : NSNotification) {
    let info = notificatio.userInfo
    //update tableview

}
```

Post on other ViewController

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil, userInfo: [String : Any])
```