# Trigger a function when user taps `Back` in detail view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, segue

I need to refresh my collectionView when user returns to that `VC` because what he/she did in the `detailVC` has affect on the previous VC data. I tried `collectionView.reloadData()` in both `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` of my `VC` has the `collectionView` in it. And It came up that when user taps the `'Back'` in `detailVC` both `viewDidLoad()` and `viewDidAppear()` do not work. So, I tried to call one of them in `detailVC` with instantiate the `firstVC`(which has the `collectionView`)
then I got an runtime error which said `collectionView is nil`. Any thoughts? (BTW, the segue between them is `ShowPush`, and I can not change it because I have to have the transition of this segue in my app.)

Here is the firstVC:

```
class SkillsController: UIViewController{

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var TAGS: [TAG] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TagCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "tagCell")
        self.sizingCell = (nib.instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil) as NSArray).firstObject as! TagCell?
        self.loadMore()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        print("back to skills")
        self.TAGS = TagManager.shared.tagList
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

`TAGS` is my data which is stored in `Realm` database.

Here is the detailVC:

```
class SeeSelectedController: UICollectionViewController {

    var TAGS: [TAG] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var layout: FSQCollectionViewAlignedLayout!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if currentTab.shared.isSkill {
            self.title = "Selected Skills"
            //init tags
            let list = RealmManager.shared.skills
            if let list = list {
                for element in list {
                    TAGS.append(TAG(n: element.value!, iS: true))
                }
            }
            collectionView?.reloadData()
        }else{
            self.title = "Selected Needs"
            //init tags
            let list = RealmManager.shared.needs
            if let list = list {
                for element in list {
                    TAGS.append(TAG(n: element.value!, iS: true))
                }
            }
            collectionView?.reloadData()
        }

        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TagCell", bundle: nil)
        collectionView?.register(nib, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "tagCell")
    }

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = TAGS[indexPath.row].name!
        let currentState = TAGS[indexPath.row].isSelected!
        TAGS[indexPath.row].isSelected = currentState ? false:true
        if currentState {
            print("deselect")
            //remove from realm
            RealmManager.shared.deleteItemFromList(type: getTypeOfTag(isSkill: currentTab.shared.isSkill), item: item)
        }else{
            print("select")
            //add to realm
            RealmManager.shared.addItemToList(type: getTypeOfTag(isSkill: currentTab.shared.isSkill), item: item)
        }
        if currentTab.shared.isSkill {
            let VC: SkillsController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SkillsController") as! SkillsController
            VC.viewDidAppear(true)
        }
        collectionView.reloadData()
        //addd
    }

}
```

So how it is working? in the `SkillsVC` user can select some tags from a pool, in the `detailVC` which is `SeeSelecteVC` he/she can drop selected tags. It is constantly changing in the Realm as you can see. The problem when user has dropped some tags in `detailVC` and press the `Back` button, the dropped tags are still looking as selected in `SkillsVC`. However when if user goes another VC and comes back to `SkillsVC` (by this way the viewDidLoad() is gonna work) the dropped tags are seems to be unselected. That's all.

Comment: `viewDidAppear()` is the right place to `collectionView.reloadData()`. ut before, you have to update the data used by the collectionView as well, which I assume you did not.

Comment: No, I am constantly updating the data, but in `detailVC` the data is meant to be updated. that is why it exists. When user decides to go back to `firstVC` data has already updated but I can not trigger the function to reload `collectionView`

Comment: you show your code, I think the issue's reason you did not show

Comment: ok the code is on its way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If what you are looking for is just to reload on back button**

What you can do is create your own custom `UIBarButtonItem` that will make you navigate backwards from your "detail view controller". What you should do next after adding your own back button is add an `IBAction` for `UIBarBUttonItem` and `pop` your "detail view controller".

Right before you do this, you should create a delegate that will be executed before the popping happens that will reload your `UICollectionView`.

**The following is not the best way to achieve what you want:**
In your `didSelectItem` for your second view controller, you are creating a new view controller here and you shouldn't force call `viewDidAppear`. Since you are creating a new `UIViewController`, you are not referencing the previous `UIViewController` that you came from and soo your `UICollectionView` is nil.

```
if currentTab.shared.isSkill {
     //remove the below lines and call the delegate here
     let VC: SkillsController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SkillsController") as! SkillsController
     VC.viewDidAppear(true)
}
collectionView.reloadData()
```

**What you should be doing is:**
You should use delegates to send callbacks to previous view controllers or perform actions.
To create a delegate-

Using the first approach (using your own back button)-

```
protocol delegateVC{

    func reloadCollectionView()
}

class SeeSelectedController: UICollectionViewController{
    //add this inside this class
    var delegate : delegateVC?
    ...

   //implement your IBAction for back button and inside it-
    ...  {

        self.delegate.reloadCollectionView()
   }
}
```

**OR the second approach i pointed out** (Just change your `didSelectItem` and it will reload the collectionView, no need to fret about back button at all and save the hassle, i strongly recommend this approach)

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let item = TAGS[indexPath.row].name!
        let currentState = TAGS[indexPath.row].isSelected!
        TAGS[indexPath.row].isSelected = currentState ? false:true
        if currentState {
            print("deselect")
            //remove from realm
            RealmManager.shared.deleteItemFromList(type: getTypeOfTag(isSkill: currentTab.shared.isSkill), item: item)
        }else{
            print("select")
            //add to realm
            RealmManager.shared.addItemToList(type: getTypeOfTag(isSkill: currentTab.shared.isSkill), item: item)
        }
        if currentTab.shared.isSkill {
           self.delegate.reloadCollectionView()
        }
    }
}
```

And in your first view controller-

```
func reloadCollectionView(){
     collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

**Note:** In your `prepareForSegue` remember to set the delegate of your detail view controller to be your first view controller

Comment: thank for your answer. I made a little research and some say `NotificationCenter` might be useful (http://stackoverflow.com/a/25921822/1404324). what do you think about that solution? I liked yours more but I need more help to implement it as I do not have any experiences with `Delegates`

Comment: Do read up on delegates as they are quite important when it comes to iOS. 
See the example i've written, it is quite simple.  Protocol is essentially how you go about using delegates. You can use `NotificationCenter` but it will require you to pass dictionary in case you need to pass arguments and removing observers and what not. Do some research as to what your personal preference is and what is better and where, don't take my word for it. There are some instances when you need notifications as well. There are plenty of tutorials regarding delegates in swift as well :)