# Deleting item in tableView by removing item from array crashes with fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I am trying to remove an item from a public static array that is been shown in a tableview. The deletion is occuring in a different viewcontroller and when I try to enter that view controller the app crashes with the error of 'Index out of range'

this is where i delete the Item

```
func removeItem (info:Dictionary<String, Any>){
    let stringKey = info[KEYS.stringKey] as! String
    for var i in 0 ..< ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.count {

        let current = ItemsViewController.itemVideosList[i]
        let currentStringKey = current[KEYS.stringKey] as! String

        if stringKey == currentStringKey {

            ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.remove(at: i)
            return
        }
    }
```

I call this method on a button click here:

```
@IBAction func FavoriteAction(_ sender: Any) {


    if Flag {
        removeFromFavorite(info: songInfo)
        Flag = false
        }
    else {
        ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.insert(songInfo, at: 0)
        favFlag = true
    }
}
```

I am populating the table view in 'ItemsViewController' viewDidLoad with this method

```
func loadItems() {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.itemsTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: reload table after deletion . Issue can be something else as well not sure though.

Comment: where do i reload the table? i cant get a reference to the table from the delete method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to loop through when deleting. This leads to ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.count being invalid after your deletion.

1. You can solve your problem simply by adding a break instead of a return

   ```
   if stringKey == currentStringKey {
       ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.remove(at: i)
       return
   }
   ```
2. More importantly, you should not modify a collection while iterating it. This leads to undesired side effects. It's better to just store the indexToDelete and then delete it outside of loop.

   ```
   func removeItem (info:Dictionary<String, Any>){
   let indexToRemove = -1
   let stringKey = info[KEYS.stringKey] as! String
   for var i in 0 ..< ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.count {

       let current = ItemsViewController.itemVideosList[i]
       let currentStringKey = current[KEYS.stringKey] as! String

       if stringKey == currentStringKey {
           indexToDelete = i            
           break
       }
   }

   ItemsViewController.itemVideosList.remove(at: indexToDelete)
   }
   ```

Note:

You could make your iteration cleaner using higher-order functions like so:

```
var list = ["a", "b", "c"]

let index = list.index { (str) -> Bool in
    if str == "b" {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is when i reload the tableview. (altho your answer is important for me also).
The prints that i added show that the item is deleted but when i try to re-enter the view controller it crashes.

Comment: @IttaiOren after deletion are you on same controller or performing some segue?

Comment: @Tushar Sharma I am on the same controller. the deletion deletes an item in a static list and when user chooses to go to that controller the list will populate the tableview

Comment: You can post a notification that the other viewController listens to. And then reloads the data

Comment: can you give me an example for this kind of notification and listener?

Comment: I found a good example and it works (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25921623/how-to-reload-tableview-from-another-view-controller-in-swift). Thanks for the help

Comment: Glad I could help :)